# Graph of quadratic equation

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics

“The points of intersection of the graph of $y=3+x-0.5x^2$  and the line $y=k$   are the solutions of the equation $10+2x-x^2=0$”

I was thinking that maybe i could find the solutions for the second equation and then find value of $k$. But thats too much work for one mark, and anyway it says to use the line $y=k$ to find the solutions. So i am supposed to find k through another method. Please help. I have my cambridge maths exam on 30 may

Comment: Please consider using mathjax

Comment: But what is the question in the problem you mention?

Comment: Good luck for your exam! Also k=-2

Comment: The first senctence is completely wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$-x^2+2x+10=0\iff -\frac12 x^2+x+3=-2$$

then $k=-2$.

Comment: Precisely the one I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$
10+2x-x^2=0
$$
$$
x=1-\sqrt{11} \text{ or }x=1+\sqrt{11}
$$
$$
y=3+x−0.5x^2
$$
$$
y=3+(1-\sqrt{11})−0.5(1-\sqrt{11})^2
$$
$$
y=-2
$$
$$
y=3+(1+\sqrt{11})−0.5(1+\sqrt{11})^2
$$
$$
y=-2
$$

Therefore since both points lie on $y=-2$, $k=-$2